# Cropping image interest regions at Matlab?

Tags: image-processing, matlab, matlab-cvst

Is there any tool or useful function at Matlab for cropping interest regions from images. For my case I need to extract texture regions from images. What are the helpful items that I might benefit from ?

Comment: Do you need just to crop an image given coordinates of cropping rectangle?

Comment: cropping inn rectangle shape

Answer (score 2):

look at `imcrop` and `roipoly` functions

Answer (score 0):

If you have to process a large number of images, try using the [Training Image Labeler](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ug/label-images-for-classification-model-training.html) app in the Computer Vision System Toolbox.